# knitr/rmarkdown/Latex: How to cross-reference figures and tables in 2 different pdf files?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I'm trying to write a scientific article and the associated supplementary materials entirely in RStudio with rmarkdown.

It seems clear that book down is the way to go to cross-reference between files (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38884378/576684), but I also would like to be able to reference figures produced in one pdf in the other pdf.

Although my latex has got quite rusty with time, I imagine it could be achieved as follows:

1. compile the article tex and SuppMat tex a first time using rmarkdown::render()
2. compile these tex files from the command line in order to keep the corresponding .aux file with their references (missing references won't be resolved at this time)
3. recompile the 2 tex files from the command line another time where all references should now be resolved

Is it a reasonable way to do it? am I overlooking something simpler?
In any case, it requires:

- a different numbering of figures in each pdf file (covered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/51337664/576684)
- to prevent rmarkdown from trashing the .aux files (it seems that pandoc doesn't allow this, hence the need to create the aux file using standalone latex)
- to tell latex to use the additional .aux file if it is found (probably using `header-includes:` in the YAML header). how can I achieve that?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: After fiddling a bit I got it all working but the last step: use reference from another aux file in the file currently being compiled… I guess this has turned to a TeX question…

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the xr package is one way to go: https://texblog.org/2016/08/23/adding-references-from-an-external-file/

so this works from R:

```
rmarkdown::render("myarticle_ms.Rmd", 
                  bookdown::pdf_book(base_format=rticles::plos_article),
                  clean=FALSE)

rmarkdown::render("myarticle_SM.Rmd", 
                  bookdown::pdf_book(base_format=rticles::plos_article),
                  clean=FALSE)

tinytex::pdflatex("myarticle_ms.tex", clean=FALSE)
tinytex::pdflatex("myarticle_SM.tex", clean=FALSE)

tinytex::pdflatex("myarticle_ms.tex")
tinytex::pdflatex("myarticle_SM.tex")
```

with the following in the YAML header of myarticle_ms.Rmd (and the corresponding one the SuppMat file header):

```
header-includes:
  \usepackage{xr} \externaldocument{myarticle_SM}
```

Hope it makes life easier for a few others :)