# Pagedown: Separate figure numbering for appendix/supplemental section?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pagedown

Is there a possibility to separate/change figure numbering for the appendix/supplemental section in an R Pagedown document?

Something analog to the question/answer in this discussion (but for pagedown!): [Rmarkdown/Bookdown: Separate figure numbering for Supplemental Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223141/rmarkdown-bookdown-separate-figure-numbering-for-supplemental-section)